# Two Vagrant VMs cannot ping each other

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vagrant

- CentOS 7 VM - 10.0.2.100
- Windows Server 2012 R2 VM - 10.0.2.15

**Goal** - Ping each other; communicate with each other

**Problem** - Cannot ping each other; communicate with each other

On the CentOS VM, I have auto_config turned off because Vagrant was having trouble automatically changing the IP for me. So I made Vagrant recognize it as 10.0.2.100 and then changed the network manually on the VM.

On the Windows VM, Vagrant defaulted the IP address to 10.0.2.15.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "master" do |master|
    master.vm.box = "centos/7"
    master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.2.100", auto_config: false
    master.vm.box      = "centos_7_v2"
    master.vm.hostname = "master.local.com"
    master.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "nodeone" do |nodeone|
    nodeone.vm.box = "windows_2012_r2_standard"
    nodeone.vm.hostname = "nodeone.local.com"
    nodeone.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    end
  end

end
```

I have the configuration --natdnshostresolver1 added to both VMs, and then added the following into my own hosts file (on my Mac).

```
10.0.2.15 nodeone.local.com
10.0.2.100 master.local.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Apparently, you just set the IP address to be in the same subnet and then add then follow `virtualbox__intnet: true` setting per https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/networking.html

```
# Master
master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.100",
  virtualbox__intnet: true

# Node
nodeone.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.110",
  virtualbox__intnet: true
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @jeffrey-wen, the solution is to add `virtual_box__intnet: true` to the inventory file. It should be noted that in doing so, you may have trouble pinging or sshing into your Vagrant boxes which are now on a new local network (as detailed [in this Ansible issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15321)).

The solution for me was to add `-c local` to any command I ran. `-c` informs Ansible of the connection type to use and defaults to `smart` which sometimes doesn't work correctly.

Sorry for posting this as an answer - I don't have enough reputation yet to post it as a comment ¯\_(ツ)_/¯